# Is the Euclidean TSP weakly NP-hard?

Tags: np-hard, traveling-salesman

So the Euclidean TSP decision problem is NP-complete (see http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0304-3975(77)90012-3 ) so the TSP optimization problem should be NP-hard.

On the other hand there is a PTAS for the Euclidean TSP (see http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/290179.290180 ).

Wikipedia says that a PTAS is not possible for strongly NP-hard Problems.

So is this a contradiction, or is the Euclidean TSP "only" weakly NP-hard?
Did I miss something else?

Comment: see also [Why we can't have FPTAS for strong NP complete problems](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/16365/why-we-cant-have-fptas-for-strong-np-complete-problems)

Comment: Why would it be a contradiction?  "Strongly NP-hard" is not the same concept as "NP-hard".

Comment: @D.W. Of course it is not. I just wanted to know where the failure in my understanding was.  Maybe the question is not optimally formulated.

Comment: You could have PTAS for Strongly NP-hard Problem!!! But you  cannot have FPTAS for Strongly NP-hard problem unless P=NP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're confusing a polynomial time approximation scheme ([PTAS](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:P#ptas)) and a **fully** polynomial time approximation scheme ([FPTAS](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:F#fptas)).  Euclidean TSP has a PTAS, but it is not an FPTAS because the polynomial increases in degree as 1 / ε decreases.  Only an FPTAS is disallowed for strongly NP-hard problems, assuming P $\neq$ NP.

Comment: feel something is missing here. has euclidean TSP been proven strongly NP hard?

Comment: @vzn [Papadimitriou 1977] show that Euclidean TSP is NP-complete. The reduction from Exact Cover by 3-Sets problem (this problem is known to be as another way of 3-Dimentional Matching problem which has reduction from 3-SAT, all these problems are known to be NP-hard in the strong sense "hard for even small number" so this implies that Euclidean TSP is NP-hard in the strong sense). [https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0304397577900123/pdf?md5=6ff26ee2b2b33adbaf35711bf8dd6b14&pid=1-s2.0-0304397577900123-main.pdf]