# Does $\#W$[1]-hardness imply approximation hardness?

Tags: complexity-theory, approximation, counting, parameterized-complexity

Let $\Pi$ be a *parametrized counting problem*, where the parameter is the solution cost, e.g. counting the number of $k$-sized vertex cover in a graph, parametrized by $k$.

Assume that $\Pi$ is [$\#W$[1]-complete](http://web.stanford.edu/~rrwill/presentations/counting-k-paths.pdf) (a known problem for example would be counting the number of simple paths of length $k$ in a graph).

Does it imply that $\Pi$ is [$APX$-hard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APX) (i.e. no [PTAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial-time_approximation_scheme) for the problem exists unless $P=NP$)?

---

Note that when discussing a parameter which is the cost of solution it makes sense to discuss the approximation hardness (e.g. [see this question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/13679/why-are-all-problems-in-fptas-also-in-fpt)), as opposed to other popular parametrizations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\mathrm{W}[1]$-hardness implies that a problem has no *eptas* unless (at least) $\mathrm{W}[1] = \mathrm{FPT}$ (having an *eptas* implies parameterized tractability for the standard solution size parameterization), but there are problems with a *ptas* that are $\mathrm{W}[1]$-hard (i.e. not $\mathrm{APX}$-hard unless $\mathrm{APX} = \mathrm{PTAS}$).

Transferring this to $\#\mathrm{W}[1]$-hardness, you can at least say that a $\#\mathrm{W}[1]$-hard problem still has no *eptas*, but I don't think a stronger statement can be made *a priori*. Turning to speculation, I suspect it's also not true that $\mathrm{APX}$-hardness immediately follows from $\#\mathrm{W}[1]$-hardness in general, though perhaps something may be said for higher classes, such as the counting version of $\mathrm{para}\text{-}\mathrm{NP}$.